# Is There a Difference Between Mouse Drivers From Different Countries?

Tags: javascript

This seems way too elementary for stack but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

The best I can seem to reach on google is the difference between mice and rats!

Essentially, part of my site won't work for a client. This client is from South Africa (where they got their computer).

I've even connected with team viewer and done the job myself through their computer where it worked fine.

When they click, they don't even get the js pop-up to confirm or deny.

Was thinking that perhaps they have some slightly different South African drivers or something? But as I say, I can't find more than rodent droppings on the subject.

Comment: No. Drivers tend not to have any specific localisation.

Comment: mouse drivers have nothing to do with javascript.  if your pop-up is not showing the most common reason is that the client has a pop up blocker activated.

Comment: In the Southern hemisphere the left and right buttons are reversed. Something to do with the Coriolis effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the drivers are international, only the installation language differs, the code is the same everywhere.